# CSS only working inline

Tags: html, css

Check it out:

[External](http://blueclick.ca/domains/blueclick.ca/new/test.php)

[Inline](http://blueclick.ca/domains/blueclick.ca/new/test2.php)

I have successfully reproduced the issue.. on the external page (test.php linking to test.css) you will see an extremely simple html page. There is one div with one image in it. It has a css style applied to it but the background (which is a couple of dropshadows) is missing.

In the second set of pages (test2.php and test2.css), the ONLY difference is that the style properties have been moved inline, everything else is IDENTICAL, but the styling now works.

How come? I've seen this situation many times before but people always like to claim that "there is obviously some overriding styling somewhere that you just forgot about or aren't noticing" but in this case I have gone out of my way to show that there is no overriding styling.

Yet it's browser independent and consistent so I'm sure there is a simple answer.

Comment: When using background images, the path is relative to the resource, not to the page. So, the inline loads the bg image and the css-ified doesn't because it does not find it

Comment: This question will never help anyone else, especially when those links stop working.

Comment: Added the CSS code for him to help future users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relative paths in external CSS files need to be relative to the CSS file, not the page.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've put the url of the image inside a css, inside css folder, the url of the background image have to start with `../`

Answer (score 1):

In your inline, you use the full path starting with `http://`

In your external, you use a relative path starting with `support/imag...`

The reason the external doesn't work is because the path to the image is incorrect.  Either use the full path (not recommended if it's on the same site as the page), or correct the relative path to make it relative to the CSS document, not to the actual page.

For example if your CSS is in a "css" folder like yours is, you usually need to start it's relative path with '../' to jump up one level before accessing your 'images' folder (or whatever the folder is).

Answer (score 0):

You can

a) Put your test.css file in the same directory as your new.html file and replace `<link rel="stylesheet" href="support/css/test.css">` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">` in your html file. Will work.

OR

b) Change the background image url from `support/images/content_bgshadow.png` to `../../support/images/content_bgshadow.png` in your test.css

Answer (score 0):

your just forget to change the path of your background image, it's now relative to your css not your html page 
http://blueclick.ca/domains/blueclick.ca/new/support/css/support/images/content_bgshadow.png image doesn't exists you should put ../images/content_bgshadow.png in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You've got wrong url in your css file. Because it's in `support/css` folder you must set path relatively to this folder, so it should be `../images/content_bgshadow.png`.